# Include static library in VS C++ project

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, visual-studio-2017, static-libraries

## Configuration I have

- Windows 10 64bit
- Visual Studio Community 2017 with Visual C++ 2017
- CMake 3.9.0
- opencv 3.3.0

## Aim

Goal is to build opencv as a static library (**.lib**) and include into a Visual C++ project which is a DLL. Everything should be compiled for x86 architecture or simply 32bit.

## Process

Latest opencv distributive does not contain dll's compiled for 32bit system and therefore, I need to compile own version. According to the opencv 2.4 documentation on ["installation in Windows"](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windows-installation). I have compiled the library with `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` option disabled and configured target project as described in ["how to build applications with OpenCV inside the Microsoft Visual Studio"](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to).

Compilation of my project fails with following errors (totally error count is greater than 800)

*Error type 1*

```
LNK2038 mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' 
doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in main.obj  
\opencv_core320d.lib(alloc.obj)
```

*Error type 2*

```
LNK2005 "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct 
std::char_traits<char> >::_Osfx(void)" (?_Osfx@?$basic_ostream@DU?
$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ) already defined in 
opencv_core320d.lib(system.obj) \msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll)
```

*Error type 3*

```
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _ippicviHSVToRGB_16u_C3R@24  
\opencv_imgproc320d.lib(color.obj)
```

I believe it may be due to uncoordinated compilation options or erroneous configuration of my project, but because I am heavy Linux user I experience difficulties with setting up these things on Windows.

## Update

After I have matched configuration shown in the screen below block of errors about code generation mismatch disappeared, but undefined references are still there.
[image: Runtime library option]

Thank you for help!

Comment: It is almost certainly due to your compiler or linker settings. Compare them between the library project and the DLL project.

Comment: can we get the CMakeLists.txt for your project that is trying to link in the opencv library? I'm guessing there is a problem here...

Comment: @g19fanatic my project is not built with CMake only opencv. My DLL is simply a win32 app project in visual studio, so I believe it's built with some visual studio rules.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve "Error type 3" add *.lib files from "staticlib" dir to "Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies". For example "_ipp" symbols are defined in "ipp_iw.lib" and "ippicvmt.lib".

Just for info. I successfully built opencv from sources as a static and shared library (as opencv_world3**.lib) using MSVS 2012 and cmake 3.9.0. But also done that with MSVS 2017 community.

PS. Maybe a TYPO but you said that you use opencv **3.3.0** but in error messages there is opencv_core**320**d.lib

PPS. "Error type 1" is the result of using static debug runtime version in opencv_core (MTd) and dynamic debug runtime in your app (MDd)

Comment: In case of prebuilt opencv package version 3.3 does not contain staticlib for x86, opencv 2.3.14 contains, but I encounter many more problems with older version if I switch to it.

Comment: So do NOT use the prebuilt opencv package :)

Comment: With own built libraries I cannot properly add them as static libraries and I cannot carry myriads of dll's along with the one I'm developing.

Comment: If you have problems with linking to prebuilt libs, you never get further until you fix linking to your own built libraries.

Comment: Exactly, I am currently stuck with linking pf either prebuilt or compiled libs and that question is devoted to this issue.

Comment: Try building a sample project with only opencv 3.3.0 static linked. And add your other "bad" dependencies one by one to discover linking conflicts.

Comment: With all the ammendments made I still receive 300+ error stating something like that `LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _ippicviMean_16s_C4R@20 referenced in function "bool __cdecl cv::ipp_mean(class cv::Mat &,class cv::Mat &,class cv::Scalar_<double> &)" (?ipp_mean@cv@@YA_NAAVMat@1@0AAV?$Scalar_@N@1@@Z) opencv_test <path>\opencv_test\opencv_core330d.lib(stat.obj)`

Comment: Here is the a cut from the list of additional dependencies that i use in my project (maybe this will be useful): ws2_32.lib
imm32.lib
winmm.lib
version.lib
uxtheme.lib
dwmapi.lib
Iphlpapi.lib
Vfw32.lib
ipp_iw.lib
ippicvmt.lib
opengl32.lib
glu32.lib
ittnotify.lib
zlib.lib
IlmImf.lib
libjasper.lib
libtiff.lib
libwebp.lib
opencv_world330.lib

Answer (score 0):

I always have the same problems. This is why I have a property sheet ready for use.

The steps to follow for static compilation are:

1. Remember to Build the INSTALL project in the CMake generated Solution. Let's call `$(OPENCV_DIR)` the folder where the install happened (usually something like `xxx\install`). You can create an environment variable for this.
2. Add in front of `[Configuration Properties]->[VC++ Directories]->[Include Directories]` `$(OPENCV_DIR)\include;`. The semicolon is to separate paths.
3. Add in front of `[Configuration Properties]->[VC++ Directories]->[Library Directories]` `$(OPENCV_DIR)\x86\vc15\staticlib;`.
4. Match the runtime library linkage mode between OpenCV and your project. If you unselect `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` by default the CRT is statically linked (/MT for Release or /MTd for Debug). If you want it dynamically linked deselect `BUILD_WITH_STATIC_CRT`. So, as you already realized, fix it in `[Configuration Properties]->[C/C++]->[Code Generation]->[Runtime Library]`.
5. Copy all filenames matching `*.lib` (`*d.lib` for Debug) and add them in `[Configuration Properties]->[Linker]->[Input]->[Additional Dependencies]` separated by semicolons.

It's quite painful, so do it once in a Property Sheet and just include it when needed.

Comment: I am probably still missing something. However, after recompilation and rechecking the project properties number of problems reduced and currently I receive only `unresolved external symbols`

Comment: @hrust If your problems are related only to unresolved external symbols, usually you have some .lib files missing from the [Additional Dependencies].  Have you tried to deselect `BUILD_WITH_DYNAMIC_IPP` during OpenCV building?